# About sql IN function

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have written on procedure as:

```
create proc proc_sample

@emp_id as nvarchar(500)
as
begin
declare @sql as varchar(500)

set @sql='
select tdate,emp_id, 
    max(convert(varchar(40),DateDiff(minute,cast(tdate + ' ' +intime as datetime), 
    Cast(isnull(tdate_out,tdate)  + ' ' +outtime as datetime))%(24*60)/60)+ 'hrs'+
    convert(varchar(40),DateDiff(minute,cast(tdate + ' ' +intime as datetime),  
    Cast(isnull(tdate_out,tdate)  + ' ' +outtime as datetime))%60)+ 'min')
    as [Worked Hour],max(intime),max(outtime),max(inremarks)
from tbl_emp_attn_log 
where emp_id in ('+@emp_id+')and tdate 
     between '2010-1-01 00:00:00' and '2011-04-09 00:00:00'  
group by tdate,emp_id order by emp_id,tdate'
end
```

But it shows the following Error:

```
Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Procedure proc_sample, Line 10
Line 10: Incorrect syntax near ' +intime as datetime), Cast(isnull(tdate_out,tdate)+'.
```

when I tried to solve this problem I could not get my desire result. So any one there to solve this

Comment: why are you running dynamic TSQL when you don't appear to need to do so?

Comment: most probably he is getting comma separated emp ids in `@emp_id`.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot: ah yes! missed that bit....then break them out into a temp table and join to it. Or one of the many others ways of handling CSV ID values

Comment: yes actually @emp_id holds comma separted ids as: @emp_id='203,509,....'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid having to use dynamic SQL, and thus loose some of the power of stored procedures, you could us a function like

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split(@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))       
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(8000))       
as       
begin       
    declare @idx int       
    declare @slice varchar(8000)       

    select @idx = 1       
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

    while @idx!= 0       
    begin       
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
        if @idx!=0       
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
        else       
            set @slice = @String       

        if(len(@slice)>0)  
            insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)       

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
        if len(@String) = 0 break       
    end   
return       
end
```

Then you can send in the values you would like to use in you IN clause like a comma separated list. In you where clause you then do

```
WHERE emp_id in (SELECT CONVERT(int, items) FROM dbo.Split(@emp_id, ',')) ...
```

This way you don't have to do dynamic SQL and the query optimizer can do a better job.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>most probably it is problem of quotes.</strike> try replacing all single quotes in with duble quotes like this.

EDIT:- you are trying to use `alias` in `CAST` function which is not permitteed.

**wrong**

```
cast(tdate + ' ' +intime as datetime)
```

**correct**

```
cast(tdate as datetime)
```

**modified query**

```
create proc proc_sample

@emp_id as nvarchar(500)
as
begin
declare @sql as varchar(500)

set @sql='
select tdate,emp_id, 
    max(convert(varchar(40),DateDiff(minute,cast(tdate as datetime), 
    Cast(isnull(tdate_out,tdate) as datetime))%(24*60)/60)+ ''hrs''+
    convert(varchar(40),DateDiff(minute,cast(tdate as datetime),  
    Cast(isnull(tdate_out,tdate) as datetime))%60)+ ''min'')
    as [Worked Hour],max(intime),max(outtime),max(inremarks)
from tbl_emp_attn_log 
where emp_id in ('+@emp_id+')and tdate 
     between ''2010-1-01 00:00:00'' and ''2011-04-09 00:00:00''  
group by tdate,emp_id order by emp_id,tdate'
end
```

Comment: your code has been compiled successfully but when I execute procedure as=> exec proc_sample @emp_id='206,506' It shows following error:Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Line 10: Incorrect syntax near 'and'.

Comment: @Nhuren the right approach is as given by @inquam in his answer and is also used by my team (to split string and put it into a temp table). Actually the string of IDs passed is also wrapped in ' so it does not works. Sorry had no time to check SO and correct my mistake.